# jquery-bing-maps click event not triggered from window marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, bing-maps, jquery-events

I am trying to trigger an event from links within Window markers placed on Bing Maps
however when I click on the links I get redirected to a new page rather than having JS to bind a function to the event

```
$('.single_address').live('click', function (evt) {

    alert('test');
    return false;
});


for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
 (function (i) {
   var location_id = locations[i].aid;
   var address_street = locations[i].d;
   // var self = this;

   self.addMarker({
    'location': locations[i].la + ',' + locations[i].lo,
    'bounds': true
   }).click(function () {self.openInfoWindow({
    'title': address_street,
    'description': '<div class="single_address"><a href="test.php#list1">Contacts at this address</a></div>'
            }, this);
        });

    })(i);
}
```

so basically the alert message is not getting displayed but the page is redirected to test.php

Using jquery-1.8.2 and Jquery Mobile 1.2

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ? `live()` has been removed in 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML code so we can see the definition of your elements. If 'single_address' in an HMTL link, then the href should be set to: 'javascript:void();'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NicolasBoonaert I hope I got you right. The link is generated by Javascript in the 'description' option, perhaps it's not noticeable due to the scrollbar. I hope that answers your question

Comment: @jerome.s I'm using jquery-1.8.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.2

Comment: So you might update the href to 'javascript:void();' to avoid the redirect to the page.

Comment: @NicolasBoonaert just tried it now but gets ignored, the alert is not showed and the page is redirected to what is href attribue. No JS errors are displayed in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have managed to  get it working, I am not sure what I was trying to do is something achievable

I have followed Bing Maps documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675210.aspx

It is either possible to make the title clickable specifying an event handler in the **titleClickHandler** property
Or, add labels with the **actions** property

```
  var infoboxOptions = {
         title:'My Infobox',
         description:'Testing actions',
         actions:[
          {label: 'test1', eventHandler: testEvent1},
          {label: 'test2', eventHandler: testEvent2}
         ]
   };
```